# How do I increase MATE volume beyond normal range in PP?

Tags: volume-control

Some videos were recorded poorly or at low volume and need augmenting to hear; is there an app for that?

Comment: Do you just want to boost the volume on your system so you can hear the videos, or do you want to boost the audio of the video files themselves, so they're louder no matter who plays them back?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to increase your system's volume, you can right-click on the sound icon in the taskbar and choose "Sound Preferences". The "Output Volume" slider at the top of the window should allow you to boost the output volume well beyond 100% (to about 150% or so)

If your videos are standalone files, you could play them in VLC; turning VLC's volume up (it goes up to 200%), in combination with turning Ubuntu MATE's own volume control up, should give you a considerable boost in volume.

Comment: I don't have any sound icon in the task-bar, that went away a while ago, don't know why, maybe during one of the updates. Before it went away, it would appear for some videos and not others; however if I go into the computer menu, Preferences> MATE volume controls, everything is already maxed out.  The problem is with online videos, like Youtube, etc., I don't want to download every video just to hear it, thanks.

Comment: I would like more volume, period. I'm not picky how to achieve it. The usual volume sliders are maxed out. Websites have their default players, there's no latitude to switch players.